# How do you perform the TPMS relearn procedure for Honda?

Tags: honda, fit, tire-pressure-monitoring-system

My daughter has a 2009 Honda Fit Sport with a TPMS system. The TPMS light is lit on her dash. What I want to know is:

- How do you perform the relearn procedure?
- Will a TPMS fault show up through OBDII diagnostics?
- If it doesn't, how do you know what's wrong with the system (what are the diagnostic steps)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do the relearn on the Fit. With a tool like

[image]

https://store.snapon.com/TPMS-Testers-Tool-Tire-Pressure-Sensor-System-P649963.aspx

or with a scantool that supports TPMS module bi directional controls.

With the tool you store each ID in the tool either manually or by querying each sensor. Plug it into the OBD2 port and it does the rest. With the scantool you need to know each sensor ID beforehand. Then you can manually enter them into the TPMS module.

The TPMS module will store codes. Assuming a bad sensor and not a wiring/module issue (very rare). You can also go into live data and check each ID for bad data. But, if you don't know where each sensor is in relation to the wheels it's not very useful. If you don't have a reader/programmer tool you'd have to break down each tire to find the bad sensor.

Comment: How do you tell a good sensor from a bad sensor?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 with a scantool it'll display nonsense data like -40 tire temp or 0 psi for tire pressure. Basically the TPMS module can't talk to the sensor. Same deal with a tool, you won't get a response when querying the sensor.